# remove "Manuscript submitted to ACM"

Tags: header-footer, front-matter, acmart

I am using `acmart` package `manuscript` option to write a report not intended to submit to ACM, yet It seems it insists on the output of "Manuscript submitted to ACM", is there any way I can remove it? TIA

```
\documentclass[review=true, screen, anonymous]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference info
\setcopyright{none}
\pagestyle{plain} % remove running headers
\title{TBD}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `acmart` class has the text `Manuscript submitted to ACM` explicitly hard-coded in `standardpagestyle` and `firstpagestyle`, so either one has to redefine those pagestyles (this will be tedious!) or applies a small patch with `\ps@firstpagestyle` etc., substituting the undesired text with empty space, which is done by `\xpatchcmd` and leaving the replacement 'slot' `{}` empty (see below)

In addition, if the document class option `manuscript` is set, the boolean 'variable' `\@ACM@manuscript` is set to true, so this should be set to false explicitly.

Small info: page styles are defined in a macro name `\ps@X`, where `X` stands for the name of the page style, i.e. `plain` or `firstpagestyle`.

Since `@` macros are involved, a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair is needed.

```
\documentclass[review=true, screen, anonymous,manuscript]{acmart}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ps@firstpagestyle}{Manuscript submitted to ACM}{}{\typeout{First patch succeeded}}{\typeout{first patch failed}}
\xpatchcmd{\ps@standardpagestyle}{Manuscript submitted to ACM}{}{\typeout{Second patch succeeded}}{\typeout{Second patch failed}}    \@ACM@manuscriptfalse% Also in titlepage
\makeatother

\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference info
\setcopyright{none}
\pagestyle{plain} % remove running headers
\title{TBD}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Just ran into this problem with the new ACM template and tried (unsuccessfully) a number of possible solutions.  Then ran across this solution while carefully reading the class documentation.

Pass the `nonacm` option to the `\documentclass` command. See Table 2 in the [`acmart` class documentation](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf).

Example:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen,timestamp,authordraft,nonacm]{acmart}
                                                       ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Only this works for me! Thanks

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :)